# how to create 2 column in UITableView

Tags: iphone

How to create two column's in UITableView....

I found for mac.. I need to create for iphone.... I found rows....How to get two column's for my UITableView... for each  individual i need to navigate.

First i need to get two column's for UITableView.

Comment: Hi.. Joe Blow....Thanks for replay....  But  my cell need to perform     detailedTextLabel with two column's and have n-number of row's...first column will load another nib file... second will load another nib.. file.

Comment: UIButton  *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
   button.frame = CGRectMake(60, 0, 50, 25); // size and position of button
   [button setTitle:@"More this date " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8]];
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to put two table views side by side, if they need to scroll independently.  Otherwise design a single cell to look like two cells, if they need to scroll in unison.

The UIPickerView allows multiple columns, but you may not want that style of scrolling interface.

Comment: .. Yeap.. I will try to customize my UITableView Cell.. I will may one cell into two. cell.... I need to maintain each cell different action.

Comment: You can have multiple buttons in any table view cell, it's more a question if you need the columns to move separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can get two columns by customizing the tableview cell. Just use custom cells and design them as you like. Use the custome cell in your tableview, and also desgin the table header, for pretty good look.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the functionality and size of scrollable view required, you might also look into using a UIScrollView and draw your columns manually.  Probably best if you are looking for a spread-sheet like experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
            UIButton  *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
            button.frame = CGRectMake(60, 0, 50, 25); // size and position of button
            [button setTitle:@"More this date " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8]];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:button];



-(IBAction)action:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"More on this date");

}
```

I-configure the above code in my cell...... i get button on my cell..... and i did my required action for the button.....

Thanks for the people who supported for my query.

Comment: How did you implement the action like the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` do? E.g: Button01 will load View02, and the Button02 will load the View08. I'm using `delegate` now, but it seems I need to judge which button was clicked & then load the specified view.